# Docker port mapping is not working on running container on windows

Tags: docker

I am trying to make my simple spring boot app to work on docker

I am running on windows 10, docker 2.2.0.5 engine 19.03.8

I tested simple nginx image and it working after start I am able to access it via "http//localhost:8000"

But when I am trying to run my app it is not working
this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

I set very basic application.properties file:

```
server.port=8080
spring.resources.static-locations:"file:./swagger-ui/"
```

then build and run with following commands:

```
docker build -t myapp-image .
docker run -p 8081:8080 myapp-image
```

docker container is running , I am able to ssh and when trying to curl some api on port 8080 all works or at least I am getting 404 error

tested telnet from my host to 127.0.0.1 8081 is accessible

but when trying to do localhost:8081/somepath getting "This page isn’t working error"

what am I missing here, please help?

Comment: Can you share application properties file?

Comment: sure, added into the question

Comment: Docker Toolbox or the Docker Desktop application?  If you can connect to the container using telnet or netcat, can you issue simple HTTP requests that way?

Comment: @PanteleevDima The way I see it, you're not `refused to connect`, that means that the request is properly reaching to Spring Boot app. Probably some path configuration might be missing. Can you check if you can access `locahost:8081/swagger-ui/index.html`?
Also, check the logs of the service. You might find something useful there.